# Embedded local video files are not playing

Tags: joomla-4.x

I have this bit of html in one of my articles:

```
<video style="width: 100% !important; height: auto !important;" controls="controls" width="384" height="288">
    <source src="files/video/uchi_uke.mpg" type="video/mpeg" />
</video>
```

I have tried replacing the path in the `src` with "/files/video/uchi_uke.mpg" and "https://ny.karateklubb.com/files/video/uchi_uke.mpg", but it's the same result. No playback.

In my Global Configuration -> Media component, both mpg and mpeg are listed in Allowed Extensions and Legal Video Extensions (File Types), and I have the mime types video/mpeg and video/mpg listed in Legal MIME Types.

Link to the article:

> https://ny.karateklubb.com/index.php/wadokai/kumiter/chudan-uke

The video file in question is there on the server, as can be confirmed by going here:

> https://ny.karateklubb.com/files/video/uchi_uke.mpg

Why isn't the video playing? I don't think it has anything to do with the browser, as I've tested on chrome on windows, firefox on windows and chrome on android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your video to mp4. See https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

And in your code

video style="width: 100% !important; height: auto !important;" controls="controls" width="384" height="288"

width="384" height="288" -- unnecessary.

Comment: That worked! I was able to convert all my videos for free at CloudConvert.com.

Comment: @Oleg  This is a "do this" answer.  Can you expand your answer to include _why_ this is a suitable solution?  Future researchers are likely to wonder why this answer works.

Comment: Dear mickmackusa. I can quote the page I linked to (https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp) but on linked page more complete information.HTML Video Formats

There are three supported video formats: MP4, WebM, and Ogg. The browser support for the different formats is:
Browser  MP4  WebM  Ogg
Edge  YES  YES  YES
Chrome  YES  YES  YES
Firefox  YES  YES  YES
Safari  YES  YES  NO
Opera  YES  YES  YES
HTML Video - Media Types
File Format  Media Type
MP4  video/mp4
WebM  video/webm
Ogg  video/ogg